# Authenticate rainloop with SSO

Tags: php, api, single-sign-on, webmail

I am using the SSO example provided by rainloop but it didn't work for me and it always redirects me to login page although the expected behavior of it should bypass the login using SSO hash.. i have check that my SSO is generating..

```
// Enable RainLoop Api and include index file 
$_ENV['RAINLOOP_INCLUDE_AS_API'] = true;
include '../../rainloop/index.php';

$email = 'user@yourdomain.com';
$pass = 'testtest';
$ssoHash = \RainLoop\Api::GetUserSsoHash($email, trim($pass));


header('Location: http://yourdomain.com/rainloop/?sso&hash='.$ssoHash);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the rainloop installation you include in your PHP file is the same which handles the SSO request that you redirect to in your header. This means that you can't handle SSO between different servers.